# colloquial conversations

Tags: questions

I have a simple question to be asked in japanese: WHY ARE YOU HERE?

I know the individual words for 'Why', 'here'. But I don't seem to know the sentence structure for these types of questions.

Anyone has an insight (colloquial and formal version?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どうしてここにいる？ *Doushite koko ni iru?* is the colloquial way. You use にいる *ni iru* to talk about the location of living being (for non-living things say にある *ni aru*. To make it polite, say どうしてここにいますか？ *Doushite koko ni imasu ka?*, *imasu* being the polite form of *iru*, and *ka* being a question marker generally used with polite forms (with plain forms it sounds either a little rough and aggressive, or like formal writing).

To go even further, you can express respect with the honorific constructions どうしてここにおられますか？ *Doushite koko ni oraremasu ka?*, どうしてこちらにいらっしゃいますか？ *Doushite kochira ni irasshaimasu ka?*, and どうしてこちらにいらっしゃいますでしょうか？ *Doushite kochira ni irasshaimasu deshou ka?* *Orareru* and *irassharu*, here conjugated to polite forms, are honorific forms of *iru* (*irassharu* is more honorific), and *kochira* is a polite form of *koko* (it can also be polite self-reference, or a neutral word for 'this way'; in the last use, it has the colloquial form こっち *kocchi*, which can be used a a self-reference, but is much less polite than *kochira*).

Of course, if you required to express respect, どうしてこちらに？ *Doushite kochira ni?* may be your best option. Incomplete sentences often sound softer and less demanding.

Comment: Thanks. If I say 'Doushite koko ni iru?' wouldn't that sound a little aggressive (and perhaps serious?) 

I meant to say 'Why are you here' for example in cases when I suddenly find someone in the office working on a sunday. But the mood is joyful/in a joking manner. Would I say the same thing?

Comment: How about「あれっ、今日はどうしたの?」, then...?